# How to sum across columns based on column label (containing a typical character)?

Tags: r, sum, conditional-statements, label, conditional-operator

Dear Stack Overflow community,

I am new on the forum, here's my first post.

My issue it the following:

I would like to sum, per row, across the columns whether the column label contains a typical character (in my case, either contains "complete" or "incomplete") and report these sums in related columns "sum_complete" and "sum_incomplete".

```
set.seed(1)
incomplete_x=1:10
incomplete_y=rnorm(10)
complete_x=runif(10)
complete_y=3:12
dt=cbind(incomplete_x,incomplete_y,complete_x,complete_y)
```

I would like to have `dt[,5]` and `dt[,6]` containing respectively:

> 0.3735462 2.1836433 2.1643714 5.5952808 5.3295078 5.1795316 7.4874291 8.7383247 9.5757814 9.6946116
>
> 3.934705  4.212143  5.651674  6.125555  7.267221  8.386114  9.013390 10.382388 11.869691 12.340349

I have been doing something like (sorry, not good at coding...):

```
for (i in 1:ncol(dt)) {
  if (grepl("incomplete",colnames(dt)[i])==TRUE) {
    dt[,"sum_incomplete"] <- rowSums(dt)
  } else {
    dt[,"sum_complete"] <- rowSums(dt)
  }
}
```

But the code doesn't work.

Could you help with this code please?
Thank you in advance for your help!

Anthony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were going in the right direction using `grep`, but the `for` loop is not needed

```
dt <- cbind(dt, rowSums(dt[, grep("^incomplete", colnames(dt))]))
dt <- cbind(dt, rowSums(dt[, grep("^complete", colnames(dt))]))

colnames(dt)[5:6] <- c("sum_incomplete", "sum_complete")
```

as a side note, it's probably best not to use `dt` for naming a matrix as it is both a function name and might be an abbreviation for a different library